# How to filter a list of required elements in list using listviewer in swt jface

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have created a list using SWT which displays a list of animals ex:cat,dog,camel,elephant. and now I need to search for a specific animal ex dog in search coloumn andonly that animal has to be displayed in the list. I have written the code to filter the list  but the list is not getting filtered and I am not able to find where the problem is. The sample code is as follows

```
final List list = new List(listComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL);


            gridData = new GridData();
            gridData.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
            gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
            gridData.verticalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
            gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
            list.setLayoutData(gridData);


            final Map<String,String> descriptionMappernewer = DescriptionParsers.getListOfFXToolMethods();
            for(String key: descriptionMappernewer.keySet())
                list.add(key);


             final MyFilter filter = new MyFilter();

            final ListViewer viewer = new ListViewer(listComposite);
            //viewer.getList();
            viewer.getList().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
            //viewer.getList();
            viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
            viewer.setInput(list);
            //viewer.setComparer( list);


            /*
            comparator = new MyViewerComparator();
            viewer.setComparator(comparator);
            viewer.setSorter(sorter);
            */

            txtName.addListener(SWT.Verify, new Listener()
            {
                @Override
                public void handleEvent(Event e)
                {
                    final String oldS = ((Text) e.widget).getText();
                    final String newS = oldS.substring(0, e.start) + e.text + oldS.substring(e.end);
                    System.out.println(newS);
                    //MyFilter filter;
                    filter.setSearchText(newS);
                    viewer.refresh();
                }
            });
            viewer.addFilter(filter);
```

The MyFilterClass is as follows

```
private static class MyFilter extends ViewerFilter
    {
        private String searchString;

        public void setSearchText(String s)
        {
            this.searchString = ".*" + s + ".*";
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean select(Viewer viewer, Object parentElement, Object element)
        {
            if (searchString == null || searchString.length() == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("no string");
                return true;
            }

            String p = (String) element;

            if (p.matches(searchString))
            {
                System.out.println(searchString);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Please help me to filter the list as I am new to jface not able to find the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List` to the `ListViewer.setInput` method - this is wrong.

The code you were given in your previous question uses a `java.util.List` which is the correct thing to use here.

So change the list to be as shown in [How to search for required elements in list using jface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25241236/2670892)

So to quote from the first answer use:

```
List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
input.add("Dodo");
input.add("Unicorn");
input.add("Wyvern");

viewer.setInput(input);
```

Comment: But in my code i have to use a swt list so which method  can be used for filtering the swt list

Comment: `ListViewer` creates the `org.eclipse.swt.List` for you internally. The `setInput` method does not set the control to use, it sets the list / array of objects to show.

Comment: Please can you help me to use which method to use to filter the list for the given code sample .

Comment: The filter should work once you use the correct list for the input.

Comment: Please can you ecplain briefly how to pass the correct list for the input for the given example .I am not getting it

Comment: @user3824589 Create a `java.util.List`, add your items, set it as the input. Don't worry about the `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List`.

Comment: As i have created many other list using  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List in the same shell and when i set a java.util.List for this only  list it throws a error so pls can you help me to  do filtering for the swt list  of  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List instead of changing it to java.util.List.

Comment: @user3824589 You don't seem to understand. You're using a `ListViewer`, internally this class uses an SWT `List`, but you don't have to take care of that one. The `ListViewer` uses an `ArrayContentProvider` which accepts either a `Collection` or an array as the input. `java.util.List` extends `Collection` and can therefore be used as the input. You can still use SWT `List`s somewhere else in your code, but there is no way to use an SWT `List` as the input of a `ListViewer`. I hope that made it clearer.

Comment: Now i need to add a mousedown event listener for list array.so how can that be done.as i guess there is no listeners for list array.so at that time how can we resolve